# Selectivity of Hydroboration Oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

[image]

Will the addition happen across both double bonds? Ordinarily you add H and OH syn and the OH anti-Markovnikov to one double bond

Hypothetical product:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{BH_3} $ can attack any of the two double bonds. Now it all depends on how many moles are being reacted in the vessel. Let us suppose there is only one mole. In the below process there is formation of chiral carbon and hence there is a pair of enantiomer.[image: this is for one double bond]

Now we consider the other one.[image]

Here there is no chiral center and hence no optical isomerism.
Hope this was helpful to you....

Comment: Is the answer mixture of a single enantiomer? If so, I have a solution.

Comment: Theoretically, BH3 can add across either double bond. However, it's more likely to react at the less hindered double bond. I think that it's more likely that it reacts with *both* double bonds, rather than it reacting *only* at the more hindered one.

Comment: But aren't both possible as they haven't mentioned the number of moles reacting?

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that the addition should be on the left double bond as it has least number of neighbouring alpha hydrogens to give it a sort of hyperconjugative delocalisation ,and thus is relatively more reactive than the double bond at the right extreme.

Comment: That's true but in that case there will be no optical isomerism due to lack chiral centre.

Comment: Which in turn implies that option d is meant to be correct.

Comment: It is anti addition and see

Comment: Small amount of diastereomer is formed but isn't enantiomer a major product